# Dynamically pass in variable into where statement

Tags: node-oracledb

I can select from database by passing dynamic variables like `:Type` and `:Code` using the following statement:

`SELECT "MSG" as "MESSAGE" FROM "TABLENAME" WHERE "TYPE" = :Type AND "CODE" = :Code`

However, let say I want to pass in the variable conditionally for `Type`. If in the database, the `Type` column has `All` value, then choose the `All` value, else if the `Type` column shows other values, then replace the `:Type` with the passed in arguments. Something like this:

```
  SELECT "MSG" as "MESSAGE" FROM "TABLENAME" 
  WHERE 
   IF "TYPE" = "All"
     "TYPE" = "All"
   ELSE 
     "TYPE" = :Type
  AND "CODE" = :Code
```

What is the correct syntax for this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

For something with a limited number of cases (two in your example), I would simply use two different SQL statements and use JavaScript logic to decide which one to execute.

You could also explore using a CASE statement in the WHERE CLAUSE or maybe some kind of UNION?